# In Android Camera parameters, What is the relation between PictureSize() , PreviewSize and display size?

Tags: android, image-processing, camera, android-camera

Consider I want a picture of size `400*400`, my camera supports picture size of `320*240`,`640*480`,`1024*768` etc...

**My 1st question:**

Which gives me better quality image in below two options

- setPictureSize to `640*480`. Once the picture is taken crop it to `480*480` then scale it into `400*400`
- setPictureSize to `1024*768`. Once the picture is taken crop it to `768*768` then scale it into `400*400`

**My 2nd question:**

I tested output of `getSupportedPreviewSize` in many android devices and in all devices it returns display resolution as one of the valid supported preview size. Is this true for all android devices?

**My 3rd question**

Does `Preview Size` affects quality of the image?

**My 4th question**

Consider I am using `FrameLayout` to preview camera, what is the relation between `preview size` and `FrameLyout`size. Should I change the dimension of the `FrameLyout` based on the size of the `Preview`

Thanks in advance. Sorry for asking lengthy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you crop it to 400x400? There is no way to tell which scaledown will turn out worse and a lot of factors apply. Generally the less scaling the better.

The getsupportedpreviewsizes will return at least one resolution in any android device with an API of 5 or greater: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()
Note: The maximum resolution of the device is not always supported, but 640X480 is almost always supported.

Picture size is the image size while preview size is used for altering the image based on the current device orientation. This can scale the image more if it is not taken care of properly. In short, it can affect the quality, but not of the actual file: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int, int)

Your frame layout may fill whatever area you have and will be stretched to fill that area. It should not affect quality of the actual picture taken.

Comment: Well answered for 1st,3rd and 4th question but I guess you did not understand my 2nd question properly. I know that it will return atleast one  value. My question was, is it true for all device that even display resolution of the device will be in the list of `getSupportedPreviewSize`

Answer (score -1):

**1** The quality of 640x480 image "cropped" to 400x400 will be better than of 480x480 scaled down to 400x400. The downside is that you loose some filed of view. But you loose in anyway, when you turn a rectangular 4:3 picture into square, so probably you can afford even less field of view. If you really need the full field of view, then go for maximum resolution and use an image processing library (e.g. OpenCV) to scale the picture down.

**2** Th answer is firm negative. Take a Nexus 10 for example. The screen is 2560 x 1600 pixels, while the highest preview size is 1920x1080 for back-facing, 1280x1024 for front-facing camera.